# DPInst.exe fails to execute from within InnoSetup on 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: driver, inno-setup, dpinst

I'm trying to install 64-bit drivers using DPInst.exe and Inno Setup.  When I execute the installer, DPInst is launched and then displays the error "DPInst.exe does not execute on your current Operating System".  This made me think that I grabbed the 32-bit version instead of the 64-bit version of DPInst.exe, but if I wait until the installer is done I can then run the DPInst manually and it executes just fine and installs the drivers.

Here is the relevant portion of my Inno Setup script:

```
[Files]
Source: "...DPInst.exe"; DestDir: {app}\Drivers; Flags: ignoreversion

[Run]
Filename: {app}\Drivers\DPInst.exe; WorkingDir: {app}\Drivers;
```

This seems pretty straightforward, so I don't know what I'm missing here.  It works if I run it outside Inno Setup, so I'm not sure why I get an error about my current OS when it runs inside Inno Setup.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Over the weekend, the machine performed a Windows update and Win 7 SP1 was installed.  Now the DPInst when called from Inno Setup works.  I then re-imaged the machine back to pre-SP1 and it again failed.  I checked the DPINST.log and found this:

```
INFO:   ****************************************
INFO:   11/25/2013 13:43:54
INFO:   Product Version 2.1.0.0.
INFO:   Version: 6.1.7600 
INFO:   Platform ID: 2 (NT)
INFO:   Service Pack: 0.0
INFO:   Suite: 0x0100, Product Type: 1
INFO:   Architecture: AMD64.
INFO:   Interactive Windows Station
INFO:   Command Line: '"D:\Program Files\Digital Audio Corporation\MicroDAC 5\Drivers\DPInst.exe"'
INFO:   DPInst is not multi-lingual.
INFO:   ****************************************
INFO:   Current working directory: 'D:\Program Files\Digital Audio Corporation\MicroDAC 5\Drivers'
INFO:   Running on path 'D:\Program Files\Digital Audio Corporation\MicroDAC 5\Drivers'
INFO:   No valid 'dpinst.xml' file provided.
ERROR:  DPInst.exe not supported on current OS.
INFO:   Returning with code 0x80000000
INFO:   11/25/2013 13:43:56
INFO:   ****************************************
INFO:   11/25/2013 13:44:42
INFO:   Product Version 2.1.0.0.
INFO:   Version: 6.0.6000 
INFO:   Platform ID: 2 (NT)
INFO:   Service Pack: 0.0
INFO:   Suite: 0x0100, Product Type: 1
INFO:   Architecture: AMD64.
INFO:   Interactive Windows Station
INFO:   Command Line: '"D:\Program Files\Digital Audio Corporation\MicroDAC 5\Drivers\DPInst.exe" '
INFO:   DPInst is not multi-lingual.
INFO:   ****************************************
INFO:   Current working directory: 'D:\Program Files\Digital Audio Corporation\MicroDAC 5\Drivers'
INFO:   Running on path 'D:\Program Files\Digital Audio Corporation\MicroDAC 5\Drivers'
INFO:   No valid 'dpinst.xml' file provided.
INFO:   Wizard cancelled by user on welcome page.
INFO:   Returning with code 0x80000000
INFO:   11/25/2013 13:44:44
```

Notice the Version field goes from 6.1.7600 to 6.0.6000.  The first run is from Inno Setup when it failed (notice ERROR) and the second run is when I run it manually.  What does the "Version" field represent?  And why would SP1 being installed make a difference?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Does your setup run elevated (as administrator) ? If you executed that application separately, did you run it as administrator ?

Comment: I get the UAC dialog asking for permission to run in elevated mode in both cases (installer and manually running DPInst.exe).

Comment: Does your Installer run in 64 or 32 bit mode?

Comment: It is running in 64-bit mode, I believe.  I have the following lines in my script: ArchitecturesAllowed=x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm trying to do the same thing but can't find a working example.

Comment: Of course SP1 Does make a difference. It is meant to fix compatibility and security issues. It fixes errors on ADO